# Gridview layout flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to show list items in gridview.count() in my code but I am unable to do it.

**Here is the code.**

```
final List<Widget> result = <Widget>[];

categoriesWidgets.addAll(result);

if (isForFavorite) {
categoriesWidgets.addAll(result);}
```

**Similar to this code below but instead i want my above code wrapped in Gridview.count**

```
String categoryCaption,

final Padding categoryTitleWidget = Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
child: Text(categoryCaption, style: style));

if (isForFavorite) {
categoriesWidgets.add(categoryTitleWidget);}
```

Comment: what is the issue here?

Comment: @OMiShah the result output is a list of items and i want to show the those items as a grid view. So how can i write the above inside the gridGriedView.count(), just the like the lower code is inside padding.

Answer (score 0):

As far I guess from your code snippet, May be you want to get something below  set `categoriesWidgets` list size in `gridview` item count.

```
 GridView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2),
              itemCount:categoriesWidgets.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: (){

                  },
                  child:categoriesWidgets[index],
                );
              }),
```

Comment: will the gridview.builder work outside build widget? Here is the link to the code for better understanding. [link](https://github.com/kulikov-dev/UnitsConverterFlutter/blob/main/lib/widgets/main/main_page.dart)

Comment: ListView(controller: _scrollController, children: categoriesWidgets)))  you want replace this listview  by gridview. right?

Comment: yes exactly, but when i change the ListView to GridView in this line of code then both the category text title and items in category are changed to grid view. Whereas I only want to show items as a grid.

Comment: Just replace listview by gridview. U can remove scrollbar.

Comment: if the above solution works don't forget to mark the question as accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry, by changing  `child: ListView(controller: _scrollController, children: categoriesWidgets)` to `GridView.count(controller: _scrollController, children: categoriesWidgets)` both the category title and item are changed to grid which i don't want. I only wanted to show only items in grid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252399/discussion-between-abu-bakar-and-babul).